# Indices of transposed csr matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to receive transpose of CSR matrix with proper indices and indptr. Using transpose method I for some reason I don't change indices attribute.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3])
>>> data = np.array([4, 1, 3, 2,1, 5, 2, 4])
>>> sample=sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
>>> print(sample.A)
[[4 1 3 0]
 [0 2 0 1]
 [2 0 5 4]]
>>> print(sample.indices)
[0 1 2 1 3 0 2 3]
>>> transposed=sample.transpose()
>>> print(transposed.A)
[[4 0 2]
 [1 2 0]
 [3 0 5]
 [0 1 4]]
>>> print(transposed.indices)
[0 1 2 1 3 0 2 3]
```

Comment: A `csr` matrix is transposed by turning it into a `csc` matrix.  `indices` now denote row values.  This is a cheap way of doing the job.   `transposed.tocsr()` might do what you want.

Comment: Ohh I haven't realized that it became csc matrix. Then it's clear, problem solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3])
data = np.array([4, 1, 3, 2,1, 5, 2, 4])
sample=sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
print(f"sample: \n{sample.toarray()}")
# array([[4, 1, 3, 0],
#        [0, 2, 0, 1],
#        [2, 0, 5, 4]])

print(f"\nsample indices: \n{sample.indices}")
# array([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
transposed=sample.transpose().tocsr()
print(f"\nsample transposed: \n{transposed.toarray()}")
# array([[4, 0, 2],
#        [1, 2, 0],
#        [3, 0, 5],
#        [0, 1, 4]])
transposed.indices
print(f"\ntransposed indices: \n{transposed.indices}")
# array([0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Thanks for the @hpaulj.